# How to show data in vf page in a table where one column is editable and the other read-only

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to make VF page with the following fields in the pic below. For a given Community Plan ID, if the value of `Year__c` is the current year (say 2016) then the values need to be displayed in a table format and they must be editable and one can add as many records (rows) as they wish. If the value of `Year__c` is the previous year, then each field needs to be displayed just as read-only. This is such that there are two columns in the table. On the right side it is the current year and one can add more rows of data if they wish. On the left side it shows the same fields for the previous year but read-only.

How to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This seems as if you are wanting us to write your page/controller for you. We are more than happy to help where you get stuck, but please attempt your task first. :)

Comment: I need a kick start.  I always do. Can I use use a standard controller or must I extend one? How to show a table in VF which is partially editable?Once someone tells me how to go about it or even better, gives me a template of code, it starts to roll.